# ASP Session times out in Java 1.8 but not 1.6. Causing huge user impact

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, jvm, applet

We run a classic ASP web application that connects to a mainframe back end via a dll that creates a session between the mainframe and client (via an IIS web server).

The website uses remote scripting so in order for the client to access the site they need JRE installed so that an applet is created locally.

We recently upgraded the JRE from 1.6 to 1.8 on a large number of users. This has lead to "random" timeouts / session disconnections for the users who have 1.8 installed. Anyone running 1.6 never times out. All users use the same webserver, so the only config difference is the version of JRE they have installed locally.

I've been told we can not roll back to 1.6 as it's out of support and poses security risks.

Does anyone have any suggestions to stop or manage the session connection in JRE 1.8?